# How to get the less than operator to work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

## The  '>' operator won't work. It returns an error in command prompt.

```
def clear_screen
  return system('cls') if Gem.win_platform?
  system('clear')
end

puts 'Hey Lovely teacher, please input the grade of the students in your class.'
    studentGrade = gets.chomp
```

#### Here the less than operator does not work

```
if studentGrade > 6
    puts 'student has passed!'
else 
    puts 'student has failed!'
end
```

Comment: the actual error text would really help

Comment: You are comparing a string to an integer.

Comment: `>` = greater than, `<` = less than

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
studentGrade = gets.to_i
```

### [Demo](https://repl.it/CU3p/1)

**Note:** `gets.chomp` take your input as `String`, you need to convert it to `Integer`. If string started with any character then it return `0`

```
> "a5".to_i
#=> 0 
> "5a".to_i
#=> 5
```

Comment: You can omit `chomp` when using `to_i`

Comment: @Stefan Good remark ! I updated my answer based on your input, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`gets.chomp` returns a `String`.
Even if you type `6`, ruby will interpret it as a `String`. Proof :

```
2.3.0 :001 > gets.chomp.class
8
 => String
```

The problem is that you compare a string to an integer, so ruby complains.

The solution is to parse `studentGrade` as an `Integer` by using `to_i`. So the solution is :

```
studentGrade = gets.to_i
```

Example :

```
2.3.0 :002 > studentGrade = gets.to_i
8
 => 8 
2.3.0 :003 > studentGrade > 6
 => true
```